# Play audio from stream in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, audio-streaming, windows-phone-7

How do i play audio from stream in the application itself. I could able to play the stream in media player. but i don't want to open media player to play the stream. i want to play the stream in my app itself.

Also the application should play the song even if its sent to background. Is it possible for an application to run certain part in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play a song when your app is in the background you'll need to use the [BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (["How to" article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

The other alternative to playing a stream/song within an app is to use a [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: I get this error on using BackgrounAudioPlayer  `Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.`

Comment: i guess the article explain to play local files.. couldn't able to play from a remote file in internet..

Comment: The articl shows using local and web based content (The Windows Phone Podcast episode.) If your file won't play, check the format is supported. Without seeing your code (or a repro) it's very hard to comment on specific problems/errors you're experiencing.

Comment: i downloaded the source explained in that article http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219073 from this link.. and the audio is playing well in the background.. But when i switch and get back to the application it starts from the beginning.. i.e When i open the application from start menu.. now by pressing the back button for long time..

Answer (score 0):

MediaElement is the best way to do this, but the problem is it wont run in background. So as an alternative we can use BackgroundAudioPlayer..